# Android - Marquee not working in every page of a ViewPager

Tags: android, gridview, android-viewpager, marquee

I have created an Android app that allows people to select products and to then purchase them.  My Product Selection screen uses a ViewPager to allow swiping the screen to display different groups of products.  The ViewPager area uses a GridView to display the items.

Some of the items have a large name and therefore is not fully shown so I have added a Marquee feature to the text so that the name of the item scrolls which allows the name to be read fully.  In general this feature works fine and the text scrolls as expected.

My issue occurs when swiping the screen; pages 1 & 2 work correctly and the text scrolls as expected but when swiping to other pages the text does not scroll.  If a page contains lots of items, I can scroll the page up/down which then seems to trigger some sort of refresh on the GridView and the text then begins to scroll correctly.

I'm unsure why the marquee works for the 1st 2 pages and not the others (unless I scroll up/down to get the grid to refresh); the only thing that I can see is that my Fragments onCreateView() method is called twice upon initialization which seems to load the 1st 2 pages into memory.  I've done a search on the Internet and this seems to be a normal process so is unlikely to be my issue.

I was wondering if there was a way to load all pages into memory (instead of just the 1st 2) or a way to force the GridView to refresh upon loading?

Any other suggestions would be great and I will give them a try.

Thanks...

Comment: Is There any error in LogCat????

Comment: There's no error in the logcat; the Marquee just doesn't work unless I scroll the page up/down so makes me think the issue is a refresh problem.

Comment: After some more investigation and testing I have managed to fix this issue.  I suggested above that the issue seemed like the 1st 2 pages were read into memory and that is why they worked; therefore I used the command "setOffscreenPageLimit()" to load all pages into memory and that seems to have fixed the problem and the Marquee now works correctly.  Does anyone see an issue with using this command like this?